# What is the point of pull/merge requests?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Is the point just to eyeball the code to check if it's "correct". How do you know if the code will actually run and not fail without accepting it and running it. (Then reverting it if it's wrong) It seems kind of convoluted. Is the testing supposed to be the responsibility of whoever initiated the pull request? Or is there some workflow to run the code before accepting it into master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many GitHub projects use [Travis (or other CI) integration](https://github.com/blog/1227-commit-status-api) to run builds across all branches, including pull requests. So the pull request is just a nice git-integrated way to submit patches to a project. I see it as a "bug report with patches" option, compared to a plain "bug report".

Comment: So if you don't have CI the responsibility of making sure everything works is up to the developer who submitted the pull/merge request? And the actual request is more of a code-style checking?

Comment: No, if you don't have CI, then it's your job to set one up, if you care about things continuing to work.

Comment: So merge requests should never be used without CI? At my job we are currently in the process of trying to integrate and promote CI throughout the company. It is not that we don't think it is a good idea, but it is not as trivial as "If you care, just set it up, else you don't care".

Comment: I'm just saying that beyond GitHub-integrated CIs, GitHub has no specific workflows to test your code for you. If you want to ask contributors to test code first, that's up to you, but it may result in far fewer pull requests arriving your way....

Comment: Ok Thanks! I think I have a clearer picture. The pull/merge request features don't actually aid in error-free collaboration, they're only part of a total solution that requires CI in order to both effectively filter out the "bad" while also allowing in the "good". Allowing everyone to push to master lets in everything, having only merge requests just blocks everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Review code

   When working on a project you want to make sure everyone on the team knows what's going in or being removed from the code base. Also, a 2nd or 3rd...or 4th or 5th set of eyes doesn't hurt.
2. Test code

   A CI service (a la TravisCI) will run automatically to make sure nothing is broken and is the first line of defense to ensure a green master build - I can't stress this step enough.
3. Discuss code

   Should this feature/request even be a part of the code base? Is there a better way to implement it?
4. Checkpoint

   Current deploy broken? It's much easier to locate a merge commit/pull request node instead of an individual commit node.
5. Communication

   There can never be enough communication around code. Someone is always out of the loop